# How to improve this code snippet to change the text style without breaking it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to adjust bold, italic and underline. I had to use this script, because I couldn't come up with a better one. This one works, but is there a better way to write it and keep the functionality?

```
//adjust fonts styles
if(decisionRouletteOption.IsBold && decisionRouletteOption.IsCursive && decisionRouletteOption.IsUnderline){
    tempResultText.fontStyle = FontStyles.Bold | FontStyles.Italic | FontStyles.Underline;
}else if(!decisionRouletteOption.IsBold && decisionRouletteOption.IsCursive && decisionRouletteOption.IsUnderline){
    tempResultText.fontStyle = FontStyles.Italic | FontStyles.Underline;
}else if(decisionRouletteOption.IsBold && !decisionRouletteOption.IsCursive && decisionRouletteOption.IsUnderline){
    tempResultText.fontStyle = FontStyles.Bold | FontStyles.Underline;
}else if(decisionRouletteOption.IsBold && decisionRouletteOption.IsCursive && !decisionRouletteOption.IsUnderline){
    tempResultText.fontStyle = FontStyles.Bold | FontStyles.Italic;
}else if(!decisionRouletteOption.IsBold && !decisionRouletteOption.IsCursive && decisionRouletteOption.IsUnderline){
    tempResultText.fontStyle = FontStyles.Underline;
}else if(!decisionRouletteOption.IsBold && decisionRouletteOption.IsCursive && !decisionRouletteOption.IsUnderline){
    tempResultText.fontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
}else if(decisionRouletteOption.IsBold && !decisionRouletteOption.IsCursive && !decisionRouletteOption.IsUnderline){
    tempResultText.fontStyle = FontStyles.Bold;
}else{
    tempResultText.fontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
}
```

I tried switch statements but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: well as you drop "decisionRouletteOption.IsCursive && decisionRouletteOption.IsUnderline" from every single line.. why not start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums support "|=" operator which helps you append flags to the value. So you could try something like this:

```
 var anyFlag = false;
 if(decisionRouletteOption.IsBold)
 {
     tempResultText.fontStyle |= FontStyles.Bold;
     anyFlag = true;
 }
 if(decisionRouletteOption.IsCursive)
 {
     tempResultText.fontStyle |= FontStyles.Italic;
     anyFlag = true;
 }
 if(decisionRouletteOption.IsUnderline)
 {
     tempResultText.fontStyle |= FontStyles.Underline;
     anyFlag = true;
 }
 if(!anyFlag)
 {
     tempResultText.fontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
 }
```

I don't know how your setup looks, but something along the lines of this snippet will clean up the code you have! Hope it helps.